# How can I upload a file from an iPad to a web server (upload servlet)

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm writing an iPad application that mimics a flash website I built.
The site uses Flash file uploader to upload files from the user's filesystem to my tomcat server.

I understand that an iPad application can sync files via iTunes to a Documents folder.
Given access to those files, how can I invoke a file upload of a selected file to the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I find in tomcats docs, the file upload just works like a standard HTTP file upload as a POST request with a multipart/mixed body. [RFC1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt)

To construct such a request you could use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251078/how-to-create-http-post-data-to-the-web-server)