# How to post a parameters to server api using HTTP POST method in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i have application in which i have a web server api .this is my api

```
http://192.168.0.68:91/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=[<EntityKey>]&Command=[GET|SET|NEW]&Token=[token]&param...n=value..n
```

RequestType in the query string expects an entity name requested which could be any of the database tables.

Command, in the query string should specify the operation which needs to be performed on the specified request type which could be GET SET or NEW or any other entity specific command.

For eg. i have a register form which allows the user to register.
RequestType for register form is register so the api request on the submit button click of register form would be

```
http://192.168.0.68:91/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=Register&Command=NEW&firstname=rocky&lastname=singh&Username=rocky14&Password=[password]&Email=[email];
```

How to post this request to server api using http post method with all these parameters and values in it so that the values will be saved in the sever table named register .Please help me in solving this problem.thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Http Post data to the web server ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251078/how-to-create-http-post-data-to-the-web-server)

Comment: The example you provided are NOT HTTP-POST, but GET

Comment: Hi @vikingosegundo , can u please explain me how to use a GET method  because this is my first web project.How can i send my values to server database through http GET method.Thanks

Comment: As you see, the values are append to the url. this is al the magic. The server recognizes, that there is a `?` and treats all following as input. This is an ancient hack to pass values to some cgi-scripts back in days when many administrators didn't activate the POST handling for there servers. If not necessary, you shouldn't use this. Use POST or PUT instead.

Comment: Hi @vikingosegundo, thanks for explanation.could u please explain me how this could be possible using HTTP POST.Actually i am having a register form which consist of 6 textfields viz firstname,lastname,username,password,retypepassword and email.when a user enters values in these fields and click on submit button the values must be saved to the server database table named UserInformation.Please help

Comment: There are plenty of post dealing with this. But first make sure, you understand the difference of GET and POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below function for posting data to web-server.

```
-(void)callCommentWebService:(NSString *)pstrCommentXML{

    NSString *soapMsg = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
    "<soap:Body>"
    "<getImageComment xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
    "<Commentsxml>%@</Commentsxml>"
    "</getImageComment>"
    "</soap:Body>"
    "</soap:Envelope>", pstrCommentXML
    ];


    //Create URL Request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.website.com/website/WebService.asmx?op=getImageComment"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Populate Headers
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];
    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];  
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (conn)
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
}
```

Here,
url = you server web-service path

pstrCommentXML = you XML file whose format defined for upload

Then you can use simple delegate methods for getting response from server.

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response 
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data 
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error 
{
    [webData release];
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
{

}
```

Hope you got the point.

Comment: Hi Nishant ,i dont have an xml file.Actually i have a register form with 6 textfields .When the user enter values in these fields and click on the submit button the values must be posted to the server database table named UserInformation.Thanks

Comment: Hi, yes I got your point. But for uploading on server, there will be some format which server will accept. (like XML format, JSON format). So what ever format is there, you can create it from app side. And just upload it. Let me know in case of anything else.

Comment: the xml format should i have to create for this.Without creating can't i save my data on server side.Could u please explain.Because this my first project on web server side.Please help

Comment: You can upload the data on webside. But there should be some format which web accept. Suppose there are many POST web-services which accept the data in string format. So just comma separated strings like sunday,monday,tuesday. And on web side there extract the data by comma and use all the parameter. So, according the web part, you have to provide data to server side. Got it. Or let me know.

Comment: No buddy, I have explain in previous comment. If server accept the data in string format then you can upload it in string format. If it accept it in integer format then you also upload it.

Comment: can u provide me some link where i can get an idea on how to send data to server

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way IMHO would be to uses [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), or it subclass [ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest).
This let you easily upload text and data via POST as if it would be filling a web form — hence it name.